# How can I force Google Apps Script to wait for user to select a button on one HtmlOutput before loading the next htmlOutput?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, modal-dialog

I am a novice/amateur javascript/Google Apps Script programmer, so please forgive me if the answer should be obvious. Also, it may be so obvious that I didn't even know the correct search term to find my answer. If so, I'm sorry for the dupe.

I am writing a Google Apps Script function that ideally would load a series of HtmlOutput windows with each subsequent window opening after the user closed the previous. However, when I try running it, the script loads all of the windows in order without waiting for the user to close the previous window.

I'm also somewhat aware that it is not best practice to use the `Utilities.sleep()` function. However, I wonder if this is the only way to achieve this in this instance. It seems that there would be a more obvious, better way.

How can I force the program to wait for the user's response before loading the next window?

Here is some sample code:

```
//THIS FUNCTION SETS UP THE HTMLOUTPUT
function setDialog(userText){
   var displayHtml = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(
     '<!DOCTYPE html>'+
     '<html>'+
     '<head>'+
        '<base target="_top">'+
     '</head>'+
     '<body>'+
        '<h1>'+userText+'</h1>'+
        '<input type="button" value="Close" '+
            'onclick="google.script.host.close()" />'+
     '</body>'+
     '</html>');
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
     .showModalDialog(displayHtml, 'Here's your HTML!');
}

//THIS FUNCTION DISPLAYS 4 DIALOGS BASED ON VARIABLES
function displayDialogs(){
   var uOne = 'One';
   var uTwo = 'Two';
   var uThree = 'Three';
   var uFour = 'Four';
   setDialog(uOne);
   setDialog(uTwo);
   setDialog(uThree);
   setDialog(uFour);
}
```

The behavior I want above would be:

1. Dialog: 'One' --> User clicks close
2. Dialog: 'Two' --> User clicks close
3. Dialog: 'Three' --> User clicks close
4. Dialog: 'Four' --> User clicks close

Instead I am getting:

1. Dialog: 'One', Dialog: 'Two', Dialog: 'Three', Dialog: 'Four' in rapid succession.
2. And then the user can click to close the 4th dialog.

Thanks in advance for the help, and I'm sorry if this is a dupe. I did search for an answer before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following modification of your code will display successive dialogs, one after the other, only when the previous one is closed, and stop when there are no more to show.

A global variable as a JSON object helps to control the flow.  The "Close" button must have a `google.script.run` function call in it before the dialog is closed in order for the next dialog to open.

```
var GLOBAL_OBJECT_FOR_NEXT_DISPLAY = {//Use all caps for Global variables
  "1":"Two",
  "2":"Three",
  "3":"Four"

}

//THIS FUNCTION SETS UP THE HTMLOUTPUT
function setDialog(userText, thisLoop){
   var displayHtml = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(
     '<!DOCTYPE html>'+
     '<html>'+
     '<head>'+
        '<base target="_top">'+
     '</head>'+
     '<body>'+
        '<h1>'+userText+'</h1>'+
        '<input type="button" value="Close" '+
            'onclick="google.script.run.showNext(' + thisLoop + ');google.script.host.close(); " />'+
     '</body>'+
     '</html>');
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
     .showModalDialog(displayHtml, "Here's your HTML!");
}

//THIS FUNCTION DISPLAYS 4 DIALOGS BASED ON VARIABLES
function displayDialogs(){
   var uOne = 'One';
   setDialog(uOne,1);
}

function showNext(count) {
  var whatNext;

  count = count.toString();
  Logger.log('count: ' + count)

  whatNext = GLOBAL_OBJECT_FOR_NEXT_DISPLAY[count];
  Logger.log('whatNext: ' + whatNext)

  if (!whatNext) {return;}//Stop if there is no next value found

  setDialog(whatNext,Number(count) + 1);

}
```

Comment: Thanks, Sandy, you've answered my question. I am fiddling with it a bit to fit my exact use case. One idea is to use an array instead of an object so that it is more easily iterable. I'm also having some issues with passing other parameters using `google.script.run` but that is better left for a separate question. Thanks again!